# How detect chrome setting "Use hardware acceleration when available" in javascript, its possible?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I attached a screenshot to understand exactly what setting we are talking about ⤵️
[image]

Hello everyone, i need your help.
I need to determine whether the user has it on or off "Use hardware acceleration when available"
to do some actions depending on this

Comment: @gre_gor I don't think so